# How to parse such type of JSON (Nested) in C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to parse such type of json in C#. how to do that if i want to parse "edit", "0001", "Password" and value of "hasParent"?

```
{
  "edit": {
    "0001": {
      "PKey": [
        "Password"
      ],
      "hasParent": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You want to put a password in your JWT?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) from that JSON and access the values like you would with a dictionary. For instance like that

```
var jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var innerJObject = JObject.Parse(jObject["0001"]); // there are better ways to do it, just check out the newtonsoft docs
```

You can also create an object structure and use [data annotation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm)

```
public class MyClass
{
   [JsonProperty("edit")]
   public MySubClass Subclass { get; set; }
   // ... more properties
}
```

Then just go ahead and use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json)`;

Comment: how to access these values? means there are lots of values like 0002,0003 and so on and Password1,Password1 and so on

Comment: If you read the sample properly you will find out. The samples provide that information. Easiest way would be to create a data structure and use JsonProperty as described above. Then just deserialize the whole object structure. Also described above.

Comment: i want to save '0001' and 'Password' keywords in another variable. how to do that?

Comment: Use jobject as described above and access the fields like you would with a dictionary.

Comment: I did, read the answer. There is a sample for jobject as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178835/discussion-between-deepak-tomar-and-alsami).